different predictions on same data, TenserflowJS
I have saved a TFJS model to a document in cloud firestore, if I run this code straight from the browser:
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(TFModeljson);
loadedModel = await 
tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(jsonObject));
const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(numericValues, [1, 
    numericValues.length]);
loadedModel.predict(inputTensor).data().then(prediction => {
    //same predictions based on the same data
}
const testvalues = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
const testTensor = tf.tensor2d(testvalues, [1,testvalues.length]);
                
loadedModel.predict(testTensor).data().then(prediction => {
   const text = "testprediction: " + prediction;
   console.log(text);
   // returns testprediction: 234.05418395996094 everytime
});

It works fine but when I try to run it in a Firebase cloud function like this:
const TFModel = JSON.parse(TFModeljson);
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(TFModel));

//test prediction on same values:
const testvalues = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
console.log(testvalues);
const tensortest = tf.tensor2d(testvalues);
            
const predictiontest = model.predict(tensortest).dataSync(); 
console.log('Test prediction:', predictiontest);    
// returns 136.88072204589844 first time
// returns 306.8353271484375 second time
// returns -390.42340087890625 third time

//continuing with code   
let type;
            
for (let i = 0; i < looplength; i++) {
    const row = data[i];    
    console.log(row);
    const tensor = tf.tensor2d([row]);
                
    const prediction = model.predict(tensor).dataSync(); 
    console.log('Prediction:', prediction);
}

I get different predictions every time and its not even close, (last runs I got back 1060.4051513671875, 949.4125366210938, 1934.115966796875, -1049.058837890625)
In both pieces of code TFModeljson is the data from Firestore. If I send 3 rows to the cloud function with the same rows I do get 3 times the same prediction back, but when I rerun this function I get another prediction again. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?
I do get the following logs in the logs explorer, they may not mean anything but I still put them here:
Hi, looks like you are running TensorFlow.js in Node.js. To 
speed things up dramatically, install our node backend, visit 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node for more details. 

and
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This 
TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network 
Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in 
performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA

and
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.


Why should we believe that these code samples are working with the exact same inputs?  In the first one, you're using numericValues as input, and in the second one, you're using some array called data.  You're also using a different way to build an input tensor from these values.  We have no idea if these contain the same data.  It would be more helpful if you eliminate the unknowns in these code samples to make them as identical as possible, ideally with hard-coded data.

Yes but I declare those variables earlier, but I now put some hardcoded data in there to show the difference between the cloud function (the predictions differ) and the browser version (works as expected)

seems learning :)

how do you mean learning?

some layers may depend on random initializations (like Dropout layers, BatchNormalization layers, etc.). If these layers are not properly initialized, the predictions might vary on each run. Setting random seed for your model important aswell.
I will attach example from my Google Cloud Project via Firebase
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

admin.initializeApp();

async function loadModelFromFirestore() {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const modelDoc = await db.collection('your-collection').doc('your-document-id').get();
    const modelJson = modelDoc.data().model; // Assuming 'model' is the field where your JSON model is stored
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(JSON.parse(modelJson)));
    
    const dummyInput = tf.zeros([1, model.inputs[0].shape[1]]);
    model.predict(dummyInput).dataSync();
    
    return model;
}

exports.predict = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const model = await loadModelFromFirestore();
        
        const inputValues = req.body.input || [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputValues, [1, inputValues.length]);
        
        const prediction = model.predict(inputTensor).dataSync();
        console.log('Prediction:', prediction);

        res.status(200).json({ prediction: prediction });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during prediction:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});


Thank you for your response, I tried to run you code but it has the same outcome, different predictions every time. I do use dropout layers in my models, the problem is that if I implement the same models in a different programming language or in a different environment, it does give consistent predictions every time. I think it must be some problem in the implementation of tenserflow in the google cloud functions envirement.
